# Devo controlar status de um sistema com uma única tabela ou várias?

Tags: sql, arquitetura-de-software, banco-de-dados

Minha pergunta é um tanto quanto conceitual e permite diversas interpretações.

Sou responsável por um sistema que usa status em diversos módulos. Status da carga, status do pedido, status do pagamento, etc. Para grupo de status há uma tabela diferente, por exemplo: StatusCarga, StatusPedido, StatusPagamento.

Entretanto, fazendo manutenção em um sistema feito por outra empresa, vi que eles têm uma única tabela de status, e todas as opções de status possíveis estão dentro desta tabela. Logo, minhas tabelas de carga, pedidos e pagamento olhariam todas para a mesma tabela Status.

Dentre estas duas formas, há uma melhor e uma pior? Há outro meio de fazer isso que eu não tenha citado aqui?

Comment: Depende muito... se todos os seus status forem apenas nomes, essa solução pode ser uma boa alternativa. Se voce possui ou possuirá no futuro campos diferentes para cada status é sugerido utilizar tabelas separadas. Mas ainda há uma terceira alternativa, criar uma tabela de status apenas com a descricao e as demais tabelas (especializadas) apontando para esta primeira com estes campos dedicados.

Comment: Bem-vindo, Anderson. Editei sua pergunta para ficar um pouco menos aberta, pois perguntas que solicitam respostas baseadas em opiniões tendem a não funcionar aqui. Elas geram muitas respostas, e nenhuma mais certa ou errada que outras. Aqui deve ser possível identificar uma resposta como sendo a correta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Devido ao domínio dos dados de cada uma das entidades citadas na pergunta, a abordagem de uma tabela de status para cada entidade é bem mais organizada e atende melhor aos requisitos de manutenção e extensibilidade normalmente presentes em projetos de grande porte.

Caso exista apenas uma tabela para controlar status de diversas entidades, tudo pode ficar bem confuso.

Suponhamos os seguintes status para cada entidade:

- Carga: separando (0), carregando (1), transportando(2) e entregue(3);
- Pedido: em-andamento (0) e realizado (1);
- Pagamento: pendente (0), realizado (1) e não-autorizado (2).

> Os números entre parênteses são os códigos de cada status.

Note que para cada entidade existe um conjunto único de status e levando em consideração que cada uma delas existe independentemente uma da outra, um `Pagamento` não pode possuir o status `carregando`, por exemplo.

Então, uma modelagem possível seria:

```
Carga
  - id

StatusCarga
  - carga_id
  - codigo
  - data
  - primary_key(carga_id, codigo)

Pedido
  - id

StatusPedido
  - pedido_id
  - codigo
  - data
  - primary_key(pedido_id, codigo)

Pagamento
  - id

StatusPagamento
  - pagamento_id
  - codigo
  - data
  - primary_key(pagamento_id, codigo)
```

Note que além da chave estrangeira para a tabela da entidade, existe o código do status e a data. Desse modo existe um histórico preciso de quando cada um deles ocorreu. Veja também que a chave primária dessas tabelas de status é composta da chave estrangeira mais o código, desse modo uma entidade nunca o repetirá, caso esse seja um requisito.

Veja no [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c805d/1) o modelo físico dessa solução.

Agora uma seleção de dados para Carga poderia ser assim:

```
#Selecionar todas as cargas
SELECT id, cidade, data,
   CASE WHEN StatusCarga.codigo = 0 THEN 'Separando'
        WHEN StatusCarga.codigo = 1 THEN 'Carregando'
        WHEN StatusCarga.codigo = 2 THEN 'Transportando'
        WHEN StatusCarga.codigo = 3 THEN 'Entregue'
        ELSE '<desconhecido>'
   END AS status
FROM Carga, StatusCarga
WHERE StatusCarga.carga_id = Carga.id;
```

Comment: Olá Fábio, muito obrigado pela resposta, muito esclarecedora. Gostei principalmente pelo campo de data que mostra quando ocorreu cada status.

Só fiquei com uma dúvida. 
Digamos que eu queira retornar o status em forma escrita, numa view por exemplo. 
Eu teria que fazer um CASE para cada Status?

Comment: Caro Andy. Sim, utilizar o `CASE` é uma opção. Atualizei a resposta e o sqlfiddle.